# Writing a string property of an object with <html:text />

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, html-input, struts-html

I've got an object in my form that contains various string properties.

When I want to print it in my JSP form I could do it with

```
<c:out value="${form.company.address}" />
```

which works perfectly.

Now I want to create an HTML input field. But when I write

`<html:text property="company.address" />`

I get an error saying

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property company.address of bean org.apache.struts.taglib.html.BEAN
```

Do you know how I can create an HTML input field with my company's address?

My bean's got the necessary corresponding getters and setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of translating this:

```
<c:out value="${UFForm.company.address}" />
```

to Struts is,

```
<html:text name="UFForm" property="company.address">
```

It means that there's a request with name `UFForm` with a bean that contains a method `getCompany()` (which I'm assuming returns a `Company` object) and that in turns has a `getAddress()` getter (if you understand what I mean). In a nutshell, the bean from request/session `UFForm`, the TagLib is accessing `getCompany().getAddress()`;

*PS* Hope that `getAddress()` doesn't return a **null** else `<html:text />` will throw an exception.

---

**Edit** To explain what I did above:

```
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private String address;

    //Setter
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    //Getter
    public String getAddress() { return this.address; }
}

public class UFForm implements Serializable {

    private Company company;

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public void getCompany() {
        if (this.company == null) {
            setCompany(new Company());
        }

        return this.company;
    }
}
```

What I did above in `<html:text />` is equivalent to

```
UFForm ufForm = ....;
String property = ufForm.getCompany().getAddress();
```

Comment: I can assign the `property` parameter twice in an `<html:text />` tag?

Comment: @Bernhard V, yes, if your parent class getter returns an object (not primitive). You can say also `user.address.postCode` inside a property field for any `<html:xxxx />` in Struts. (for a bean called `User`).

Comment: @Bernhard V, sorry...property cannot be declared twice....I've edited my solution. Thanks for spotting it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your bean should have corresponding setter and getter methods.

Html form

```
<html:text property="name" size="10" maxlength="10">
```

Corresponding bean.

```
public class AddressForm 
{
  private String name=null;

  public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the getter/setter for the company? From your code it seems like there is a bean inside your Form named company who's address you are trying to print.

Comment: If so, Getter and setter are essential for both the beans.

Comment: I've got them for both. If I haven't got them, then I guess `<c:out value="${UFForm.company.address}" />` wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting the value for the text box with:

```
<html:text property="company.address" />
```

You are in fact saying to Struts to do:

```
formObject.getCompany().getAddress();
```

So you must have a getter for the company (which must not return null or the next operation will fail) and a setter for the address on the company object. The setters/getters must be public. This must already be the case since you can do the following with no error:

```
<c:out value="${UFForm.company.address}" />
```

Now, the thing that bugs me is this part: `${UFForm.`. When you use JSTL you are accessing the form explicitly. With the `<html:text>` you access a property on the form implicitly. This implicit form is provided by the enclosing `<html:form>` tag. Do you have the `<html:text>` inside a `<html:form>`?

The form bean is located/created/exposed based on the form bean specification for the associated `ActionMapping` so check your mapping also.

Comment: Struts actually is doing `getCompany().getAddress()` and not `setAddress()`.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: You are correct! Somehow I associated the <html:input> with setting the value and unconsciously used a setter. The form formObject.getCompany().getAddress() is used for getting the value and formObject.getCompany().setAddress(...) for setting it. I corrected my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.